# jQuery change Handler Not Fired

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a little jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1wkwdja7/

For some reason the change event is not firing when I set the `value` property of the `inputField` to "Barney". Typing text into the input field causes the event to fire but I need to have the event fire whenever the `value` property of the `input` changes, even if that property is changed programmatically, as it is in my example.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you explain more,what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: @all -- Sorry, I may not have been clear in the OP. I updated it to (hopefully) be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

https://api.jquery.com/change/

as you can see in the yellow note changing the value with JavaScript wont fire the event. You can fire it using .trigger( "change" )